# Compute $\sup_{n\in\mathbb N}\mathbb ES_n$ and $\mathbb E\sup_{n\in\mathbb N}S_n$, where $(S_n)$ a Markov chain.

Tags: probability, markov-chains

Let $(S_n)$ a Markov chain on $\mathbb N$ such that $S_0=1$ almost surely and $$\mathbb P(S_{i+1}=k\mid S_i=j)=p(j,k)=\begin{cases}\frac{1}{2}&k\in\{j-1,j+1\}\text{ and }j\neq 0\\ 1&k=j=0\\0&\text{otherwise.}\end{cases}.$$

Prove $\sup_{n\in\mathbb N}\mathbb E( S_n)<\infty $ and $\mathbb E(\sup_{n\in\mathbb N}S_n)=\infty $.

I have some difficulties to do it.

- What I tried for the first one is :

$$\mathbb E(S_n)=\sum_{k=1}^\infty k\mathbb P(S_n=k)=\sum_{k=1}^{n+1}k\mathbb P(S_n=k),$$

because after time $n$, the process $S_n$ is at state $n+1$ at most. Then I tried to compute $\mathbb P(S_n=k)$, and I have difficulties with that. Let denote $P_p(i)=\mathbb P\{S_p=i\}$. What I see is
\begin{align*}
\mathbb P(S_n=k)&=p(k-1,k)P_{n-1}(k-1)+p(k+1,k)P_{n-1}(k+1)\\
&=\frac{1}{2}(P_{n-1}(k-1)+P_{n-1}(k+1))\\
&=\frac{1}{2}(p(k-2,k-1)P_{n-2}(k-2)+p(k,k-1)P_{n-2}(k)+p(k,k+1)P_{n-2}(k)+p(k+2,k+1)P_{n-2}(k+2))\\
&=\frac{1}{2^2}(P_{n-2}(k-2)+2P_{n-2}(k)+P_{n-2}(k+2))
\end{align*}

but when I continue, things become more and more complicated. So, I guess there is a trick. Any idea ?

- For the other one, I don't really know. What I tried is to compute $\mathbb P(\sup_{n\in\mathbb N}S_n\geq k)$, and then use the fact that $\mathbb E[\sup_{n\in\mathbb N}S_n]=\sum_{k=0}^\infty \mathbb P(\sup_{n\in\mathbb N}S_n\geq k)$, but I couldn't find $\mathbb P(\sup_{n\in\mathbb N}S_n\geq k)=\mathbb P\{\exists m\leq n: S_m=k\}$.

Any idea ?

Answer (score 1):

You need to go step-by-step. Specifically:

- Observe that $S_{k+1} = S_k + {\bf 1}_{\{S_k >0\}} X_{k+1}$, where $X_{k+1}$ is $1$ or $-1$ w.p. $1/2$ each, and is independent of $S_0,\dots,S_k$. It therefore follows that $E[S_{k+1}] =E[S_k]  + P(S_k>0)*0 = E[S_k]$. Therefore $E[S_k]$. Since we assume $E[S_0]=0$, it follows that $E[S_k]=0$ for all $k\ge 0$.
- Now look at the partial sums of the $X_k$'s. Let $1+Y_n = \sum_{k=1}^n X_k$. By construction, $Y_n=S_n$ for $n=1,2,\dots$, until the first time $Y$ hits zero, from  which time $S$ remains at zero.  Because $Y$ is simple symmetric random walk on ${\mathbb Z}$ we know this time is finite a.s. Let $M =\sup S_n$. Then $0\le S_n\le M$ for all $n \ge 0$, and, as argued above, $\lim_{n\to\infty} S_n = 0$ a.s. Therefore, if $E[M]<\infty$, it follows from dominated convergence that $\lim_{n\to\infty} E[S_n]=E[ 0] =0$. This contradicts the first part, as $E[S_n]=1$ for all $n\ge 0$.

Hope this helps!